# Вопрос по перегрузке шаблоных функций в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Читаю книжку Джосатиса про шаблоны. Наткнулся там на один пример (40-41 стр.) и не могу его понять. Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template < class T >
inline T const& mymax( T const& arg1, T const& arg2 )
{
    std::cout << "max1" << std::endl;
    return ( arg1 > arg2 ) ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template < class T >
inline char const* mymax( char const* arg1, char const* arg2 )
{
    std::cout << "max2" << std::endl;
    return strcmp( arg1, arg2 ) < 0 ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template < class T >
inline T const& mymax( T const& arg1, T const& arg2, T const& arg3 )
{
    std::cout << "max3" << std::endl;
    return mymax( mymax( arg1, arg2 ), arg3 );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const char* s1 = "Hello";
    const char* s2 = "World";
    const char* s3 = "All";
    std::cout << mymax( s1, s2, s3 ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В результате выдается:

```
max3
max1
max1
All
```

Там даётся объяснение, но я всё равно его не понял почему не используется вот эта функция:

```
inline char const* mymax( char const* arg1, char const* arg2 )
```

У Джосатиса написано:
Проблема заключается в том, что если мы вызываем max() для трёх С-строк, то инструкция

```
mymax( mymax( arg1, arg2 ), arg3 )
```

становится некорректной. Это происходит потому, что в max() для с-строк создаётся новая временная локальная переменная, которую функция возвращает по ссылке. Как можно вернуть ссылку локальной переменной? Она же уничтожится после `}`
и как мне сделать так, чтобы использовалась эта функция:

```
inline char const* mymax( char const* arg1, char const* arg2 )
```

?

Comment: А откуда max4 взялся!?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хороший способ в неизвестной ситуации понять, какая именно подстановка происходит в том или ином случае состоит в том, чтобы **слегка видоизменить фрагменты кода.**

---

*Рассмотрим  первый дополнительный пример:*

```
template <typename T>
inline T const& mymax(T const& arg1, T const& arg2)
{
    std::cout << "max1" << std::endl;
    return ( arg1 > arg2 ) ? arg1 : arg2;
}

inline char const* mymax( char const* arg1, char const* arg2 )
{
    std::cout << "max1" << std::endl;
    return ( arg1 > arg2 ) ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& mymax(T const& arg1, T const& arg2, T const& arg3)
{
    std::cout << "max3" << std::endl;
    return mymax(mymax(arg1, arg2), arg3);
}
```

В данном примере я сделал вторую функцию нешаблонной. Приоритет выбора у нешаблонной функции больше, нежели у шаблонной, поэтому подставляется именно она. Этот код компилится, однако **он некорректен.**

Дело в том, что результат выражения `mymax(arg1, arg2)` должен положиться в какую-то временную переменную *(типа `const char*`)*, чтобы передаться в функцию `mymax(..., arg3)`. Когда мы потом попытаемся вернуть `T const&` на эту переменную, произойдет плохая вещь.

---

*Рассмотрим второй дополнительный пример:*

```
template <typename T>
inline T const& mymax(T const& arg1, T const& arg2)
{
    std::cout << "max1" << std::endl;
    return ( arg1 > arg2 ) ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template <>
inline const char* const& mymax(const char* const& arg1, const char* const& arg2)
{
    std::cout << "max2" << std::endl;
    return strcmp( arg1, arg2 ) < 0 ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& mymax(T const& arg1, T const& arg2, T const& arg3)
{
    std::cout << "max3" << std::endl;
    return mymax( mymax( arg1, arg2 ), arg3 );
}
```

Это - один из корректных способов вызвать функцию, работающую с `const char*` в нашем примере. Функция `max2` здесь сделана специализацией функции `max1` для типа `<const char*>`.

Отмечу, что, несмотря на то, что функции возвращают значения по константным ссылкам, в данной ситуации **ничего очень страшного в этом нет**. Обычно же возвращение константной ссылки из `standalone` функции всегда привлекает внимание как потенциальная ошибка и достаточно часто ей является.

---

*Рассмотрим третий дополнительный пример: (самый важный)*

```
template <typename T>
inline const char* mymax(const char* arg1, const char* arg2)
{
    std::cout << "max2" << std::endl;
    return strcmp( arg1, arg2 ) < 0 ? arg1 : arg2;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& mymax(T const& arg1, T const& arg2, T const& arg3)
{
    std::cout << "max3" << std::endl;
    return mymax( mymax( arg1, arg2 ), arg3 );
}
```

Этот пример не компилируется. Дело в том, что по стандарту `C++` `implicit` преобразование типа `const char* const& ---> const char*` допустимо, но не в шаблонной функции. Это означает, что для функции с двумя аргументами `mymax(arg1, arg2)` не найти подходящую подстановку и, естественно, это ошибка компиляции.

---

**Вывод:**

По третьему примеру мы увидели, что шаблонная функция с таким аргументом вообще не рассматривается как потенциальная подстановка для соответствующего шаблона. Именно по этой причине в исходном примере из книжки Вандервурта происходит подстановка `max1` *(т.к она - единственная возможная)*. **Как сделать так, чтобы вызывалась подстановка `max2`, я уже написал.**

---

*Дополнительные примечания:*

За такое в нормальном проекте бьют и бьют беспощадно.

Люди, которые пишут `template-based` код, должны уметь писать код на шаблонах, который не заставляет задумываться о выбираемой подстановке. В этом случае это можно было решить с помощью, например, `boost::enable_if` и трейтсы `boost::is_pointer`. В общем случае - схожим образом, пользуясь принципом [**SFINAE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) и другими возможностями современного шаблонного `C++`.

*При желании могу продемонстрировать, в какую красоту может выродиться даже этот пример.*

**И еще.** Пользуйтесь `std::string` и `умными указателями`. Это практически полностью исключает не-ссылочные типы из шаблонов и сильно уменьшает мозговые затраты на анализ подстановок.

Comment: "Дело в том, что результат выражения mymax(arg1, arg2) должен положиться в какую-то временную переменную (типа const char*), чтобы передаться в функцию mymax(..., arg3)." - эта строка мне понятна. Вызывается inline char const* mymax( char const* arg1, char const* arg2 ), возвращается const char*. Ок. А вот дальше: "...Когда мы потом попытаемся вернуть T const& на эту переменную, произойдет плохая вещь..." потом - это где? (извиняюсь за не понимание). Я не вижу где мы возвращаем T const&

Comment: mymax(arg1, arg2) - возвращает указатель на const char, arg3 - ссылка на указатель на const char. Получается результат mymax(arg1, arg2) передаётся некорректный, т.е. получается: return mymax(<что-то некорректное>, arg3);   Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @G71 `mymax(mymax(arg1, arg2), arg3);` ---------> T const&`, т.е, т.к тип результата функции `T const&`, то мы возвращаем ссылку на локальную переменную, сконструированную с помощью функции `(mymax(arg1, arg2)`, чего делать нельзя.